# "parse error, expecting , or ;" when connecting to server

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my code:

```
<?php db_connect.php

    echo "connecting to DB..."
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "*****";

    $databaseName = "atlas_test";
    $tableName = "sites";

    $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

        if(!$con){
            die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

    echo "DB connect successful..."

?>
```

...and I'm getting the following error message when attempting to run the page:

"parse error...expecting ',' or ';' in db_connect.php, line 4..."

Comment: Make sure you're not missing a `;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

echo needs to end with a ;.

This is not a connection error; a basic PHP mistake. The parse error is a good hint. Missing ; errors will often have the error line on the next, because that's where php first notices it should have seen a ; on the line before.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
echo "connecting to DB..."
```

Should look like this:

```
echo "connecting to DB...";
```

That echo is on line 3 and doesn't have a semicolon right now, so when PHP reads the echo on line 4 it freaks out (that's why it's referencing line 4 even though the problem seems to be on line 3)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot semi-colons after your echo statements.

```
echo "connecting to DB...";

echo "DB connect successful...";
```